# Authenticate to linkedin

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am trying to write a code that get some user's linkedin profile and just print it

this is my code

```
from linkedin import linkedin

CONSUMER_KEY = "XXXXX"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "XXXXX"
RETURN_URL = r"http://localhost:8000"
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                                  RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

a = application.get_profile(member_url=my_url)
print(a)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Linkedin/main.py", line 28, in <module>
a = application.get_profile(member_url=my_url)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\python_linkedin-4.2-py3.4.egg\linkedin\linkedin.py", line 189, in get_profile
response = self.make_request('GET', url, params=params, headers=headers)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\python_linkedin-4.2-py3.4.egg\linkedin\linkedin.py", line 169, in make_request
params.update({'oauth2_access_token': self.authentication.token.access_token})
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access_token'
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. Try this

As per the documentation. Access token must be generated to grand access to the application.

```
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(API_KEY, API_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token=authentication.get_access_token())

print authentication.authorization_url
```

When you grant access to the application, you will be redirected to the return url with the following query strings appended to your RETURN_URL:

```
"http://localhost:8000/?code=AQTXrv3Pe1iWS0EQvLg0NJA8ju_XuiadXACqHennhWih7iRyDSzAm5jaf3R7I8&state=ea34a04b91c72863c82878d2b8f1836c"
```

Copy the code manually and set like

```
 authentication.authorization_code = 'AQTXrv3Pe1iWS0EQvLg0NJA8ju_XuiadXACqHennhWih7iRyDSzAm5jaf3R7I8'

 authentication.get_access_token() #AQTFtPILQkJzXHrHtyQ0rjLe3W0I
 application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token='AQTFtPILQkJzXHrHtyQ0rjLe3W0I')
```

Comment: I get an error "AssertionError: You must first get the authorization code"

Comment: have updated the answer. Need to carefully follow the documentation

Comment: what do y mean by 'grant access'? What should I do to do that so I can find the authorization code automatically?

Comment: and how do I know the query string that appended to the url?